# Add custom handler on flask 404, 500 pages

Tags: python, flask

I have a handler that wraps a function and does some logging and a few other things, almost like middleware. I want to wrap that around flask's default 404, 500 replies. How would this be done? For example:

```
@app.errorhandler(404)
@my_handler
def error404(*args, **kwargs):
    return "404 - page not found", 404
    # how to instead return the existing flask 404 call/page?
```

Basically, I just want to execute the `error404` function but pass a handler around it. What should I return then?

Comment: Have you tried to return at least something despite existance `@my_handler`? If you return `render_template`, `redirect`, or something else you need - everything will be great, at the first glance.

Comment: @mrEvgenX, yes my current response is `return "404 - page not found", 404`. Here I'm looking literally to call the original Flask-404 function without modifying it (other than injecting my middleware code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspiring [this example](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/errorhandling/#generic-exception-handlers) I tried this and it seems to work in the way you need.

```
@app.errorhandler(404)
@my_handler
def error404(e):
    return e.get_response()
```